# ExecutorService Performance Issues

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, executorservice

I've trying to use the Executor Service to run multiple Tasks in parallel among the cores of my PC, so far Windows Resource Manager tells me I am using 100% of my CPU (4 cores btw) but there's little to no improvements over a sequential aproach. This is the code I'm using.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class NNTEST implements Callable<Object> throws Exception {

public long id;
public int m = 1000000000;
public double average;
public Random semilla = new Random();

public NNTEST(long sem) {
    this.id = sem;
    semilla.setSeed(sem);
}

@Override
public Object call() throws Exception {
    return doComputation();
}

public double doComputation() {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        average = average + semilla.nextInt();
    }
    average = average / m;
    return average;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    List<Callable<Object>> list = new ArrayList<>(4);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        NNTEST tes = new NNTEST(i);
        list.add(tes);
    }

    try {
        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<Future<Object>> lista = es.invokeAll(list);

        System.out.println("Multi-Threaded lasted: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t));
        es.shutdown();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        NNTEST ts = new NNTEST(j);
        ts.call();
    }
    System.out.println("Sequential lasted: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t1));
}
}
```

The code above outputs this:

```
Multi-Threaded lasted: 56104
Sequential lasted: 52616
```

It takes ~12 seconds to finish one call to NNTEST, which is consistent in sequential mode (12*4)=52.6 seconds it takes to finish the 4 runs. But my problem is with Executor Service, since my PC has 4 cores, and if each core handles a thread, shouldn't it finished the 4 runs in ~12 seconds as each core is executing and independent Task of NNTEST? Is there something I am missing?

P.D.: I've looked into this thread (pun intended) as they seem to have a similar problem but I am using a Random for each object of NNTEST. [ExecutorService slow multi thread performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155608/executorservice-slow-multi-thread-performance)

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to get rid of the `Random` stuff? Make sure your `doComputation()` does not execute synchronously, e.g that threads do not wait for a lock, held by another  thread. Try simply waiting with `Thread.sleep(12000)` in your `NNTEST.call()`.

Comment: It appears to be the use of Random. When I remove that from the "difficult problem" it speeds up as could be expected.

Comment: As Ralf said, the problem was the use of Random.

Comment: You are setting seed multiple times. set seed only once and use SecureRandom if your application needs more secure RNG.

Answer (score -3):

i do not know much about this..but according to me..you are using **public double average** which is **Global variable** and you are **mutating it** again and again and parallel approch does not do well if you are changing the state of the variable..try after transforming **doComputaion method** into **Pure Function.**.watch this video on Asynchronus programing and java Streams by Venket Subramanium..you will get much clearification https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQERMVABRrQ..i tried but i did not get much because i am just a java fresher..

Comment: Please use correct English and not texting shorthand

Comment: ok..thank you for informing..i will not do that again..

Comment: Not a problem. So could you edit your answer to fix the English? Also, provide a link to the video as [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Asynchronous+programing+and+java+Streams+Venkat+Subramaniam) reveals four or more. Which video are you referring to exactly?