# Spring REST client - force response before method finishes

Tags: java, spring, email, rest, spring-mvc

I'm writing a REST service with Spring Web 4.0.5 and one of called methods is sending e-mail (with javax mail). Sending mail takes some time, but I would like to be able to send HTTP response (no matter what response, e.g. 200) BEFORE this method finishes - so before the mail is sent. Is it even possible? Preferably without multithreading?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/mails", produces = "application/json")
public class RestMailService{

@Autowired
MailService mailService;

@RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void sendMail(){
mailService.sendMail();
}
}
```

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: The problem statement is that you want to complete the request (by replying 200) before the email is sent. This is the definition of multithreading -- the email thread runs separately from the main request/response thread.  Why do you want to do it without a separate thread?

Comment: How about using a messaging server? Create a message in your controller with all the information you need to send the email and process the messages in a separate process or thread

Answer (score 0):

I believe all possible solutions include multithreading. The thread will be either directly started by you or hidden behind messaging or something similar.

if you were to go with multi-threading after all please use some `Executor` instead of below suggested `new Thread(...).start()`

I would also note that returning HTTP 200 before the operation finishes may somewhat confuse the user as the code suggests the operation was successful where in fact the operation maybe didn't even start yet.

Comment: I feel it is not a very good to choice to go with the overhead to choosing an executor service for such a tiny task. He just wants to launch one thread. Refer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647990/executorservices-surprising-performance-break-even-point-rules-of-thumb

Comment: `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` will launch exactly this one thread and reuse it ...

Comment: But why would you want to reuse it when the task just needs to send one email. It just has to run once. As the name of executorService suggests, it is a threadPool, which is not required. As you know, there is an overhead in submitting tasks to executor services, which is not needed in this scenario

Comment: How is guaranteed the URL mapping /test will be accessed exactly once? Also with the executor you get all the shutdown stuff for free, it is just better. There is hardly a scenario for `new Thread(...)` in java these days.

Comment: I'm absolutely aware that it's bad, really bad thing to do - there is dozen of possibilities why something can go wrong and sending 200 is just not right- but, well, a customer is always right and I can't do nothing about it.

Comment: OK, nevermind, @Async works good enough. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Good point, wasn't aware of `@Async`. Found this helpful link if you're interested: https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/07/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-introducing-servlet-3-async-support. What it really does is it has `Executor` behind and submits the task into a separate `Thread` ... But it's handy you have annotation for it rather than having own `Executor`. You made a good research here :)